# Is it possible to access some sort of system error log on S60 devices?

Tags: logging, mobile, symbian, s60

this my first shot at this awesome new (to me) programmers site, I hope someone is capable of enlightening me some :)

Does anyone know if it is is possible to access some sort of error log on s60 devices? The only thing i can find that is somewhat related is a log of recent send/received packets and calls... The emulator is not a option since i need to test different WAP-Push scenarios, and my problem is that sometimes nothing happens at all when my mobile receives the Push msg, but I can see in the sparse log that i received some sort of sms... but no error or nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no single system error log on Symbian OS. There is a system logger, of course, but each component/subsystem logs to a different place and has a different policy on how/if logging can be enabled.
Unfortunately, IIRC the messaging components only write log files in debug builds, which isn't going to help you on a production device.

If the device is doing nothing on receiving a WAP-Push message, it is mostly likely a malformed payload (or possibly no watcher on the receiving port).

Might be worth posting your exact problem WRT the message and seeing if someone can help?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I feared so... I'll try and create a specific question on the OMA-EMN WAP-push which is causing me the trouble.